# Getting selected element of python list

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

I have a list of 6 elements. I get it as a dropdown through `bootstrap-select`. I can receive element of list in the console only if the form is submitted for handling.

Main question is:

**How to make it so that when I select an element, I can immediately get it(print it) in the console, before submitting the form?**

`app.py`

```
description = ['one','two','three','four','five','six']

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        docs = request.form.getlist('sel')
        print(docs)
        return render_template('login.html', description=description)
    return render_template('login.html', description=description)
```

`login.html`

```
      <form action="" method="POST" class="form-inline">
        <select id='sel' name='sel' class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
          {% for desc in description %}
            <option value="{{desc}}">{{desc}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Identify</button>
      </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('select').selectpicker();
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print in the console, you don't need to work on the `app.py`, however, you need to work on your `login.html`.

To enable this, your answer is `onchange`, which is predefined for the `<select>`, captures your data when you select an option. No need to have a submit button either.

**UPDATED ANSWER:** *The `<p>` waits for the value, which is being set inside our function `printValue()`*

```
<select id='sel' name='sel' class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" onchange="printValue(this)">
   {% for desc in description %}
      <option value="{{desc}}">{{desc}}</option>
   {% endfor %}
</select>
<p id="mySelectedValue" style="margin-top: 10px;"></p>



<!-- In your script, call your function, which prints the data in your console-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printValue(selectedItem){
       $('#mySelectedValue').html(selectedItem.value);
    }
</script>
```

In the method `printValue()`, you print your data value using the method :). You can do anything, here, like adding to selected item to your array or Map. It is upto, we're just printing in console for the sake of requirement :)

**This is the SNIPPET for the REFERENCE on how onchange works in SELECT.**

```js
function printValue(selectedItem){
  console.log(selectedItem.value);
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="your_id" onchange="printValue(this)">
     <option value="Value1" selected>Value1</option>
     <option value="Value2">Value2</option>
     <option value="Value3">Value3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: could you please clarify how to get it on the html page?

Comment: I have shown it to you @abby, in the code itself. What did you not understand in the code?

Comment: Or you want to show the selected item in your `HTML Page` rather than `console.log()`, was that your question @abby?

Comment: yes. I want to show the selected item in your HTML Page rather than console.log()

Comment: @abby, I have updated the answer, make sure you have `JQuery` imported in your `HTML file`, else, you will get error for using this `$('mySelectedItem').html()`. Cos, '$' is used to call the item using `jQuery`. If you get the thing which you were looking for, **You can mark this answer, and upvote it** so that people can find the right answer, when they come up to your question :)